# Setting up EditText with "url" inputType

Tags: android, url, android-edittext

I am trying to make an `EditText` such that, when I click it, a keyboard containing ".com" appears, because a URL is to be entered into the `EditText`.

I tried to use this:

```
android:inputType="textUri"
```

but it is not working. How do I do it?

Comment: Some devices wont support this `textUri` .. It is device dependent. Leave it like that, It will work fine on standard devices.or manually process it

Comment: I am testing it on an emulator.Do emulators support this?

Comment: Need to check that, Try to check it on real device, Or you can test on samsung lab. which has all their devices through virtualization

Comment: thanks.. the emulator was not supporting textUri as u said.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try this one

```
<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
        />
```

android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
use this property for that.

Comment: there is not www button with "textWebEmailAddress" , i'm using "textUri"

Answer (score 4):

You can use inputType as `textWebEmailAddress` or `textEmailAddress`. Specs say it is device dependent but honestly I did not find any difference. Purpose of using this is you can use the **@** and **.com** keys in the keypad. I tried both on samsung Galaxy S5 and keypad is the same.

[image]